# jQuery Modal not opening second time on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am developing a generic function to display jQuery Modal on click event.
 It is showing modal popup for the first time but on second time its showing error like below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function
```

This is the code:

```
function initPopup(params) {
        jQuery('#pci-popup-dialog').remove();
        jQuery('<div id="pci-popup-dialog" style="display:none;" ></div>').appendTo('body');        
        var src='',title='',dataType='html',loadType='S';
        var w = 700;
        var h = 700;
        if (params.src != '' || params.src != undefined) {
            src = params.src;
        }
        if (src == '') {
            return false; // return nothing to show
        }
        if (params.title != '' && params.title != undefined) {
            title = params.title;
        }
        if (params.dataType != '' && params.dataType != undefined) {
            dataType = params.dataType;
        }

        if (params.width != '' && params.width != undefined) {
            w = params.width;
        } else {
            w = 700;
        }
        if (params.height != '' && params.height != undefined) {
            h = params.height;
        } else {
            h = 700;
        }
        if (params.loadType != '' && params.loadType != undefined) {
            loadType = params.loadType;
        }
        if (loadType == 'A') { //ajax content loading
            requestRunning = true;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType : dataType,
                url: src,
                success: function (data) { 
                    // init url popup box
                    jQuery("#pci-popup-dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        title: "Pyramid Popup",
                        width: parseInt(w),
                        height: parseInt(h)
                    });
                    jQuery("#pci-popup-dialog").html(data);
                    jQuery("#pci-popup-dialog").dialog({
                        title: title,width: w,height: h
                    }).dialog("open");
                },
                complete: function() {
                    requestRunning = false;
                }
            }); 
        } else { // static content loading
            jQuery("#pci-popup-dialog").html(src);
                jQuery("#pci-popup-dialog").dialog({
                  title: title,width: w,height: h
                }).dialog("open");
        }
    }
```

Below is the click function:

```
var requestRunning = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var nav = jQuery('#main-navigation');
        nav.find('li>a').on('click',function(e){
            var menu = '',src='';
            var menu = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
            if (menu == 'Finance Calendar') {
                e.preventDefault();
                src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                var params = {};
                params.src = src+'&subwin=1&embed=1'; // appending subwin and embed
                params.title = 'Financial Calender';
                params.loadType = 'A'; // Ajax call to make
                if (requestRunning) { // don't do anything if an AJAX request is pending
                    return;
                }
                initPopup(params);
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as i am wondering what is missing..

Comment: your code is working fine with the parameters that I am running it with, if you could reproduce it in a JS fiddle, it would be easier to figure out

Comment: it is working for me in first click but second time failing i don't know whether it has anything to do with DOM.

Comment: JS fiddle i never used will give it a try

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0Luokaa/3/ this is my fiddle but its not working i have included jquery js , ui js and ui css... can anybody look into it